# Columns to rows transpose

Tags: mysql, sql

I am having trouble with transposing the table from this:

[image: Original table]

To this:

[image: The required table]

Comment: Welcome to SO. I'm not one for hyperbole, but this has been asked and answered literally a billion times on this site.

Comment: Do a `GROUP BY`, and use `case` _expressions_ to do conditional aggregation.

Comment: Thx for a tip, I am trying to find out something in here...

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT time,
       CASE WHEN tag='A' THEN value END AS `A`,
       CASE WHEN tag='B' THEN value END AS `B`,
       CASE WHEN tag='C' THEN value END AS `C`,
       CASE WHEN tag='D' THEN value END AS `D`
FROM Table
GROUP BY time
```

Comment: Thank you for that, but the table I have done is just an example, in fact tags are more complicated and there is like thousends of records....